# Is it possible to access the Apache IgnitieRDD from C/C++ Application?

Tags: apache-spark, rdd, ignite

I would like to share data between Spark Executor and C++ process. Apart from storing the data as file in in-memory FS like Tachyon/IgniteFS, is there any other efficient method?

Answer (score 0):

Ignite provides Spark with the ability to store results of its executions and share them between different spark jobs in a shared RDD call [IgniteRDD](https://apacheignite-fs.readme.io/docs/ignitecontext-igniterdd).

In the nutshell IgniteRDD is a distributed named cache that can be accessed directly using basic cache.get like operations. It means that if you use [Ignite C++](https://apacheignite-cpp.readme.io/docs/) you can interact with such a cache, that is used by IgniteRDD as well, using basic cache API.